# Calling Web service using Curl with telnet connection

Tags: curl, telnet, webservice-client

Right now I am trying to call a Web service using Curl command from Unix platform. The Web service is available on external server. I can connect the external server using telnet only. The Web service uses basis authentication and I have to provide a username and password.

Can anyone please help me with correct way to execute this ?

Comment: Are you asking how to provide credentials with curl? it's well documented.
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--basic

Comment: Do you have an example of the way that you're trying?

Comment: This is command what I am trying:   curl -header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:login" --basic -u username:password --data @test.xml url

Comment: @Eddie My concern is how to call web service from unix which is exposed via telnet connection

Comment: I tried to connect to the external web service. I am able to connect to the server but I am not getting any response from the external server. Somewhere I found below command we can try to check if the server is responding or not after the connection is established: 

telnet server port 
Trying Server... 
Connected to server. 
Escape character is '^]'. 
POST / 

But I am not getting any response for the server on sending this command. Do you have any clue if this is correct way to test whether the server is responding at all or not ?

Comment: I have tried calling the Web service using Curl and able to reach the server side. but i am getting 500 Server Internal Error with message as "The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'URL' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or ......".

Any leads to tackle this issue ?

Answer (score 14):

If you don't need curl, and just want to test the local web service over telnet connection you can just type the appropriate HTTP commands.

```
$ telnet remotehost 80
Trying IP.IP.IP.IP...
Connected to remotehost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction:urn:login
Authorization: Basic base64encodedstring


# need 2 carriage returns above to denote completion of request body.
```

But if you want curl for any reason, it seems Curls "TELNET" function would work to pass curl command through a telnet connection.

`curl telnet://remotehost`

> TELNET
>       The curl telnet support is basic and very easy to use. Curl passes all data   passed to it on stdin to the remote server. Connect to a
>   remote telnet   server using a command line similar to:
>
> ```
>     curl telnet://remote.server.com
> ```
>
> And enter the data to pass to the server on stdin. The result will be sent   to stdout or to the file you specify with -o.
>       You might want the -N/--no-buffer option to switch off the buffered output   for slow connections or similar.
>       Pass options to the telnet protocol negotiation, by using the -t option. To   tell the server we use a vt100 terminal, try something
>   like:
>
> ```
>     curl -tTTYPE=vt100 telnet://remote.server.com
> ```
>
> Other interesting options for it -t include:
>
> - XDISPLOC= Sets the X display location.
> - NEW_ENV= Sets an environment variable.
>     NOTE: The telnet protocol does not specify any way to login with a specified   user and password so curl can't do that automatically. To
>     do that, you need   to track when the login prompt is received and
>     send the username and   password accordingly.

Comment: works to test mysql (3306) and redis (6379)!!